# Posting formdata using jquery ajax post

Tags: jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

I have a bootstrap modal form code below

```
    @*Modal form Create*@
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog" id="DivCreateEnrolledDevices">
    <div class="modal-dialog" @*role="document"*@>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Create New Devices</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="DivDevicesCreate">
                    <div id="sdvPartial" style="height:200px">

                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="btnSave" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"  onclick="SaveChanges()" >Save Changes</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That I use to display a partial view code below

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
        @*<h4>EnrolledDevicesModel</h4>
    <hr />*@
        <form id="dvCreateFrm">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceKeyID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceKeyID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceKeyID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StoreBranchID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StoreBranchID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, @value = "0" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StoreBranchID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display:none">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EnrolledDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EnrolledDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EnrolledDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DeviceKey, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlDeviceKey", TempData["DeviceKey"] as SelectList, "Click to select")

                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceKey, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceKey, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    @*<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />*@
                    @*<button id="btnCreateDv" type="submit" style="display:none">Submit</button>*@
                    @*@Html.ActionLink("Create","Create","EnrolledDevices",new{@class="btn btn-primary")*@
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

And I use jquery ajax to post data whenever the save change button is clicked script below

```
function SaveChanges() {
$('#btnCreateDv').click()
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
var urlCreateDev = $('#urlCreateDev').val()
var frm = $('#dvCreateFrm').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/EnrolledDevices/Create' /*'@Url.Action("Create","EnrolledDevices")'*/ /**/,
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'apllication/html; charset-utf-8',
    data: { frm, token },
    datatype: 'html',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#DivCreateEnrolledDevices').modal('hide')
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {

        alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(error);
    }
})
```

}
and my controller code is like

```
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        LoadFormData( collection);
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

but for some reason no data is being sent to the controller

```
        private void LoadFormData(FormCollection frm)
    {
        nEnrolledDevicesModel.DeviceKeyID = Convert.ToInt32(frm["DeviceKeyID"]);
        nEnrolledDevicesModel.DeviceKey = frm["DeviceKey"].ToString();
        nEnrolledDevicesModel.DeviceName = frm["DeviceName"].ToString();
    }
```

I got null all over the above code

I just can't figure out what I have done wrong

Can I get some help here

Thanks in advance

Schleid

Comment: Is your  `partial view code` being renderred in the modal ? I am not so clear why you are calling `saveChanges` in the modal

Comment: To save informations

Comment: You have a type in the code you posted: "apllication/html"

Answer (score 0):

For the routing to work correctly ASP.NET needs to be able to map the types being posted and the types being received.

You are posting a serialised object of `#dvCreateFrm`, which is the whole HTML form, not just the data.

> var frm = $('#dvCreateFrm').serialize();

I've never seen this approach (and it might be acceptable), but typically you would just post the relevant data.

To being resolving your issues;

Create a controller that takes a single string and update your JS post to pass a single string.

```
public ActionResult NewEndpoint(string myObject )
{
 ...
}
```

```
var myObject = "Somevalue".serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: '/EnrolledDevices/NewEndpoint' /**/,
    type: 'Post',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset-utf-8',
    data: { myObject },
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
```

Once you have this working you can iteratively add more complexity - either as a single single complex object, or lots of separate fields.